# SSIS Conditional Split Error - The expression evaluated to NULL, but the "Conditional Split" requires a Boolean results

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, conditional-split

It is my first time using this software. I am trying to split the value but it is showing this and I do not have any null have when I see my source but when I preview it, it shows null value in the first 200 columns but I have only 15 columns.

> Error: 0xC020902B at Data Flow Task, Conditional Split [2]: The expression "[Copy of RATE_INR] > 1000" on "Conditional Split.Outputs[Case 1]" evaluated to NULL, but the "Conditional Split" requires a Boolean results. Modify the error row disposition on the output to treat this result as False (Ignore Failure) or to redirect this row to the error output (Redirect Row).  The expression results must be Boolean for a Conditional Split.  A NULL expression result is an error.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the following expression in your conditional split component:

```
[Copy of RATE_INR] > 1000
```

As mentioned in the error message, this expression is evaluated as `NULL` which throws an exception since the conditional split component requires a boolean result (True/False).

You can solve this problem by using the [REPLACENULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replacenull-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
REPLACENULL([Copy of RATE_INR],0) > 1000
```

Or

```
REPLACENULL([Copy of RATE_INR] > 1000, False)
```